# passing array to server via JSON.stringify() and getting strange result

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am developing an app on node.js, express.js and mongodb. My task is to pass an array to server-side and insert it to db. I've searched throughout the web and found that I need to stringify my array via JSON.stringify(), but when I console it on server side it looks strange and every attempt to use JSON.parse() ends with error.
Here is an array which is passed through JSON.stringify():

```
    [{
    "city": "London",
    "date": "20.11.2015",
    "sector": "A",
    "row": "1",
    "place": "1"
}, {
    "city": "London",
    "date": "20.11.2015",
    "sector": "A",
    "row": "1",
    "place": "2"
}, {
    "city": "London",
    "date": "20.11.2015",
    "sector": "A",
    "row": "2",
    "place": "1"
}, {
    "city": "London",
    "date": "20.11.2015",
    "sector": "A",
    "row": "2",
    "place": "2"
}, {
    "city": "London",
    "date": "20.11.2015",
    "sector": "B",
    "row": "1",
    "place": "1"
}, {
    "city": "London",
    "date": "20.11.2015",
    "sector": "B",
    "row": "1",
    "place": "2"
}, {
    "city": "London",
    "date": "20.11.2015",
    "sector": "B",
    "row": "2",
    "place": "1"
}, {
    "city": "London",
    "date": "20.11.2015",
    "sector": "B",
    "row": "2",
    "place": "2"
}]
```

when I pass it to server side it looks like this:

```
{ '[{"city":"London","date":"20.11.2015","sector":"A","row":"1","place":"1"},{"city":"London","date":"20.11.2015","sector":"A","row":"1","place":"2"},{"city":"London","date":"20.11.2015","sector":"A","row":"2","place":"1"},{"city":"London","date":"20.11.2015","sector":"A","row":"2","place":"2"},{"city":"London","date":"20.11.2015","sector":"B","row":"1","place":"1"},{"city":"London","date":"20.11.2015","sector":"B","row":"1","place":"2"},{"city":"London","date":"20.11.2015","sector":"B","row":"2","place":"1"},{"city":"London","date":"20.11.2015","sector":"B","row":"2","place":"2"}]': ''}
```

and any attempt to parse it leads to 500 error. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you passing it to the server?

Comment: @epascarello

`$.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/tickets/addticket",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
                });`

Comment: How are you trying to parse it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you see what it is doing? It is using the JSON you passed up as the key with no value.

You can just do

```
$.ajax({ 
   method: "POST", 
   url: "/tickets/addticket", 
   dataType: "json",
   data : { val : JSON.stringify(dataToSend) }
}
```

and the node.js read the querystring value for val

Other option is to set the content type

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/tickets/addticket", 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)}
);
```

Comment: First way is right too, just would need to change how you were getting the data, but the second way is normally how it is done.